# Xubuntu 18.04.2 - USB CD-RW won't write

Tags: usb, permissions, cd, burning

I'm running Xubuntu 18.04.2 on a Mac Mini. Because the internal DVD-RW drive is dead, I bought an external USB CD-RW and DVD read drive. When I put in a blank CD-R, the blank disk shows on the desktop. But my burning program Xfburn won't recognize the drive or write to it. The attached graphic shows what my Disks program shows for the drive:

[image]

Based on similar posts in other forums, I pulled up the following info from command prompts. Does anyone have any idea how I can activate the write function for the device so it can burn CD's? (I know this drive can't write DVD's as the info says.) Thanks!

---

```
msgeek@Navi2:~$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic

msgeek@Navi2:~$ cdrecord -prcap
wodim: Operation not permitted. Warning: Cannot raise RLIMIT_MEMLOCK limits.
Device was not specified. Trying to find an appropriate drive...
Detected CD-R drive: /dev/cdrw
Using /dev/cdrom of unknown capabilities
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 0
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'Optiarc '
Identification : 'CDRWDVD CRX890A '
Revision       : 'PH03'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-ROM.

Drive capabilities, per MMC-3 page 2A:

  Does read CD-R media
  Does write CD-R media
  Does read CD-RW media
  Does write CD-RW media
  Does read DVD-ROM media
  Does read DVD-R media
  Does not write DVD-R media
  Does read DVD-RAM media
  Does not write DVD-RAM media
  Does support test writing

  Does read Mode 2 Form 1 blocks
  Does read Mode 2 Form 2 blocks
  Does read digital audio blocks
  Does restart non-streamed digital audio reads accurately
  Does support Buffer-Underrun-Free recording
  Does read multi-session CDs
  Does read fixed-packet CD media using Method 2
  Does not read CD bar code
  Does read R-W subcode information
  Does not return R-W subcode de-interleaved and error-corrected
  Does read raw P-W subcode data from lead in
  Does return CD media catalog number
  Does return CD ISRC information
  Does support C2 error pointers
  Does not deliver composite A/V data

  Does play audio CDs
  Number of volume control levels: 256
  Does support individual volume control setting for each channel
  Does support independent mute setting for each channel
  Does not support digital output on port 1
  Does not support digital output on port 2

  Loading mechanism type: tray
  Does support ejection of CD via START/STOP command
  Does not lock media on power up via prevent jumper
  Does allow media to be locked in the drive via PREVENT/ALLOW command
  Is not currently in a media-locked state
  Does not support changing side of disk
  Does not have load-empty-slot-in-changer feature
  Does not support Individual Disk Present feature

  Maximum read  speed:  4234 kB/s (CD  24x, DVD  3x)
  Current read  speed:  4234 kB/s (CD  24x, DVD  3x)
  Maximum write speed:  4234 kB/s (CD  24x, DVD  3x)
  Current write speed:  4234 kB/s (CD  24x, DVD  3x)
  Rotational control selected: CLV/PCAV
  Buffer size in KB: 2048
  Copy management revision supported: 1
  Number of supported write speeds: 4
  Write speed # 0:  4234 kB/s CLV/PCAV (CD  24x, DVD  3x)
  Write speed # 1:  3528 kB/s CLV/PCAV (CD  20x, DVD  2x)
  Write speed # 2:  2822 kB/s CLV/PCAV (CD  16x, DVD  2x)
  Write speed # 3:  1764 kB/s CLV/PCAV (CD  10x, DVD  1x)

Supported CD-RW media types according to MMC-4 feature 0x37:
  Does write multi speed       CD-RW media
  Does write high  speed       CD-RW media
  Does write ultra high speed  CD-RW media
  Does write ultra high speed+ CD-RW media


msgeek@Navi2:~$ inxi -d
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 532.3GB (38.9% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: TOSHIBA_MQ01ABF0 size: 500.1GB
           ID-2: USB /dev/sdb model: v150w size: 32.2GB
           Optical-1: /dev/sr0 model: N/A dev-links: cdrom,cdrw,dvd
           Features: speed: 24x multisession: yes
           audio: yes dvd: yes rw: cd-r,cd-rw
```

------UPDATE 7/13/2019:

**The user who operates Xfburn needs effective read-write permission for the device file of the burner (here /dev/sr0). Your screenshot says "Read-Only". The drive must be able to recognize the medium. Your screenshot says "Media --". Xfburn uses libburn, not cdrecord. Inspection proposal for a libburn program, with blank medium inserted: cdrskin -v dev=/dev/sr0 -toc Please post the result. – Thomas Schmitt yesterday**

I tried to run cdrskin, and got this message:
        Command 'cdrskin' not found, but can be installed with:

```
    sudo apt install cdrskin
```

I did so. It installed cdrskin. The Disks program still shows  /dev/sr0 (Read-Only). Then I did:

```
    msgeek@Navi2:~$ cdrskin -v dev=/dev/sr0 -toc
    cdrskin 1.4.8 : limited cdrecord compatibility wrapper for libburn
    cdrskin: verbosity level : 1
    cdrskin: NOTE : greying out all drives besides given dev='/dev/sr0'
    cdrskin: scanning for devices ...
    cdrskin: ... scanning for devices done
    cdrskin: pseudo-atip on drive 0
    cdrskin: status 1 burn_disc_blank "The drive holds a blank disc"
    scsidev: '4,0,0'
    Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
    Vendor_info    : 'Optiarc'
    Identifikation : 'CDRWDVD CRX890A'
    Revision       : 'PH03'
    Drive id       : '30651360 1599125                '
    Driver flags   : BURNFREE
    Supported modes: TAO SAO
    cdrskin: burn_drive_get_write_speed = 4234  (24.0x)
    Current: CD-R
    Profile: 0x0010 (DVD-ROM)
    Profile: 0x0008 (CD-ROM)
    Profile: 0x0009 (CD-R) (current)
    Profile: 0x000A (CD-RW)
    ATIP info from disk:
    Is not erasable
    ATIP start of lead in:  -11634 (97:26/66)
    ATIP start of lead out: 359846 (79:59/71)
    1T speed low:  10 1T speed high: 24
    Product Id:    97m26s66f/79m59s71f
    Producer:      CMC Magnetics Corporation
    Manufacturer: CMC Magnetics Corporation
    Media summary: 0 sessions, 0 tracks, blank CD-R
```

**Please edit your question and add the output of the command groups. Chances are you might be missing the cdrom group from your account. – Terrance yesterday**

I did this, and got this result:
        msgeek adm dialout fax cdrom floppy tape sudo audio dip video plugdev netdev lpadmin scanner pulse pulse-access sambashare

So, I don't have a group for cdrom. How do I add it? Meanwhile...

**The output of ls -l /dev/sr0, of getfacl /dev/sr0, and of whoami would further help to clarify the permission situation. – Thomas Schmitt yesterday**

```
    msgeek@Navi2:~$ ls -l /dev/sr0, of getfacl /dev/sr0
    ls: cannot access '/dev/sr0,': No such file or directory
    ls: cannot access 'of': No such file or directory
    ls: cannot access 'getfacl': No such file or directory
     brw-rw----+ 1 root cdrom 11, 0 Jul 13 21:27 /dev/sr0

    whoami gives the result msgeek - the person who set up the computer for me.
```

I am very new to Linux, so hopefully you can provide some advice about where to go from here. Thanks in advance!

------UPDATE 7/15/2019:
The permission situation looks ok. ("of" was meant as textual "or" and "getfacl" is a command to get ACLs. Whatever, membership in group "cdrom" gives you the permission to open the drive read-write.) cdrskin would be willing to burn the CD-R. So should be Xfburn. What happens if you choose action "Burn Image" ? Does the menu window show your burner's name under "Burning device" ? ("Optiarc CDRWDVD CRX890A") If so, then you are just mistaken by the display of "Composition" actions. If not, then i am out of ideas. – Thomas Schmitt yesterday

I understand. I make typos too. Well, inasmuch as I don't have group **cdrom** and nobody has told me how to create it or install it, I need more info there.

So I did this:
        msgeek@Navi2:~$ getfacl /dev/sr0
        getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
        # file: dev/sr0
        # owner: root
        # group: cdrom
        user::rw-
        user:msgeek:rw-
        group::rw-
        mask::rw-
        other::---
So this command suggests that I DO have the group **cdrom** on my system. So I ran the command groups again and I got...

```
    msgeek adm dialout fax cdrom floppy tape sudo audio dip video plugdev netdev lpadmin scanner pulse pulse-access sambashare
```

So now I have **cdrom** in my groups. The Disks display shows no write capability still. I went back and ran:

```
    msgeek@Navi2:~$ getfacl /dev/sr0
    getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
    # file: dev/sr0
    # owner: root
    # group: cdrom
    user::rw-
    user:msgeek:rw-
    group::rw-
    mask::rw-
    other::---
```

Clear as mud. Running the command **cdrskin -v dev=/dev/sr0 -toc**  provides the same result.  I entered in the command **burn image** and got this:

```
    msgeek@Navi2:~$ burn image

    Command 'burn' not found, but can be installed with:

    sudo apt install burn
```

So I went ahead and installed it. Now I try the command **burn image** and...

```
    msgeek@Navi2:~$ burn image
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/burnlib/burn.py", line 42, in <module>
        import audio
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/burnlib/audio.py", line 28, in <module>
        import eyeD3
    ImportError: No module named eyeD3
```

So, I run the **Disks** program and it shows some things slightly different, but still shows "read only" for the disk. 
[image: Still No Write Access]

I thank you for your help, Thomas. I'm as confounded as ever, even though perhaps progress has been made. (I don't know what these installs did to my system but it still seems to be working.) Any other advice from you or the other helpers here would be appreciated. I'll give you my recipe for Sour Cream Coffee Cake if you can get the drive to write, I swear!

Comment: The user who operates Xfburn needs effective read-write permission for
the device file of the burner (here /dev/sr0). Your screenshot says 
"Read-Only". The drive must be able to recognize the medium. Your
screenshot says "Media --".
Xfburn uses libburn, not cdrecord. Inspection proposal for a libburn 
program, with blank medium inserted:

cdrskin -v dev=/dev/sr0 -toc

Please post the result.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1157686/edit) your question and add the output of the command `groups`.  Chances are you might be missing the `cdrom` group from your account.

Comment: The output of `ls -l /dev/sr0`, of `getfacl /dev/sr0`, and of `whoami`
would further help to clarify the permission situation.

Comment: The permission situation looks ok. ("of" was meant as textual "or" and 
"getfacl" is a command to get ACLs. Whatever, membership in group "cdrom"
gives you the permission to open the drive read-write.)
cdrskin would be willing to burn the CD-R. So should be Xfburn.
What happens if you choose action "Burn Image" ? Does the menu window 
show your burner's name under "Burning device" ? ("Optiarc CDRWDVD CRX890A")
If so, then you are just mistaken by the display of "Composition" actions.
If not, then i am out of ideas.

Comment: So you have rw-permission by ACL and by being member of "cdrom". All well
so far. My question is what symptom exactly makes you think that Xfburn 
does not work for you. Messages ? Pop-up window texts ? Whatever:
If you want to burn a prepared CD image then try the following cdrskin run
with a suitable file name instead of "my_image.iso":
`cdrskin -v dev=/dev/sr0 -sao -eject my_image.iso`

Comment: The cdrskin command must be written in one single line. Not in two lines,
as my web browser shows my comment.

Comment: Suggestion: OP said "[...] Xfburn won't recognize the drive or write to it". This reminds me of Ubuntu many years ago: I tried few different CD writer programs, but only Brasero worked for me back then. Try use Brasero: Run `sudo apt-get install brasero` in terminal, then run Brasero and check if hardware is recognized and test burn CD.

Comment: Also, the "Read-only" label in the Disks program is misleading. Whether you have a CD-R or a CD-RW disc in tray, the label will not change anyway. The correct indicator is whatever program that shows "blank CD" (otherwise "closed CD").

Comment: Thomas Schmitt and  clearkimura, thank you! After installing Brasero, I was able to write to the CD on the drive - but only twice. After that, the drive ceased responding, wouldn't eject the disk and wouldn't even open up with the pinhole. However, I'm certain you solved my problem. As promised, I'll send both of you the recipe I mentioned. In private messages only; you other people want it, help me with another matter and I'll send it to you. Thanks again!

Comment: Nuts, can't send private messages to either of you. So here's the recipe:

Mrs. Esther Reed’s Sour Cream Coffee Cake
This cake keeps well and even travels well. 
Preheat the oven to 350° F. Grease a tube pan (like the ones used for angel food cake) or a 9 x 9 inch square pan. 

In your mixer cream together:
½ cup (one stick) of butter or margarine
1 cup granulated sugar

After smooth, blend into the batter:

2 large eggs
1 teaspoon vanilla extract
 
(cont'd in next comment)

Comment: In a separate bowl, use a wire whisk (or a flour sifter) to blend together:
2 cups flour
1 teaspoon baking powder
¼ teaspoon baking soda
½ teaspoon salt

In another separate bowl, blend with a fork:
½ cup brown sugar
2 teaspoons ground cinnamon
2 teaspoons vanilla extract
½ cup finely chopped walnuts or pecans (optional)

Into the butter mixture, blend in alternately the flour mixture and:
1 cup sour cream or yogurt
Blend the batter smoothly after each addition.

Comment: Spread about half the batter into the tube pan or square pan. Smooth it out with a spatula. Then, sprinkle half the brown sugar mixture evenly on top of that layer. Top that with the rest of the batter, spread out evenly, and the rest of the brown sugar mixture.

Bake it at 350° F for 40 to 50 minutes, or until a toothpick inserted into the cake comes out clean.

Comment: If you baked it in a tube pan, allow the pan to cool 10 minutes. Loosen the cake around the sides of the tube pan, lift out the center hub, loosen the cake from the bottom (and possibly center post), then carefully put the cake on a plate to serve it. If you baked in a square pan, let it cool for 10 minutes and just serve it from the pan.

To serve it, wrap the cake in plastic wrap or put it in a sealed cake carrier. It will keep for several days. You can also freeze the cake, wrapped airtight in aluminum foil, then let it defrost in the refrigerator.

Comment: @tomreedtoon Dear OP, feel free to [self-answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) this question by rewriting your upvoted comment into a proper answer. You can accept your own answer immediately since this question is more than two days old. P.S.: So I guess your CD-RW drive has reached its end of life? You can plug into another computer to clarify and explain in your answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I bought a different external USB/DVD writer. I find that sometimes xfburn will occasionally work, but Brasero seems to be more reliable. Thanks for your help on this, and please try the cake recipe.